# Object reference not set to an instance of object when trying to change TextBox text

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm creating a downloader in vb.net. It works fine, except I'm getting an object reference not set to an instance of object error when I change the checked status of one of my radio buttons after the first download.

I've tried disposing the WebClient after the download has finished, but that still isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents httpClient As WebClient

    Dim UserName As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim USER As String = Environment.UserName
    Dim SAVE As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Destination As String
    Dim URL As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        UserName = txtUserName.Text
        Password = txtPassword.Text

        URL = txtURL.Text



        Destination = txtLocation.Text
        Filename = txtFilename.Text

        SAVE = "C:\Users\" & USER & "\Desktop\" & txtName.Text & "\" & Destination & "\" & Filename

        httpClient = New WebClient

        Try
            httpClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
            httpClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(URL), SAVE)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Critical")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub httpClient_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles httpClient.DownloadProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        Label6.Text = CInt(e.BytesReceived / 1048576) & " MB"

        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show(Filename & "has been successfully downloaded!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Label6.Text = Nothing
            txtURL.Text = Nothing
            txtLocation = Nothing
            txtFilename = Nothing
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            If rdoAVI.Checked = True Then rdoAVI.Checked = False
            If rdoMP4.Checked = True Then rdoMP4.Checked = False
            If rdoMKV.Checked = True Then rdoMKV.Checked = False
            httpClient.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoAVI_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoAVI.CheckedChanged
        If rdoAVI.Checked = True Then
            txtFilename.Text = txtName.Text & " S" & txtSeason.Text & " E" & txtEpisode.Text & ".avi"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoMP4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoMP4.CheckedChanged
        If rdoMP4.Checked = True Then
            txtFilename.Text = txtName.Text & " S" & txtSeason.Text & " E" & txtEpisode.Text & ".mp4"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoMKV_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoMKV.CheckedChanged
        If rdoMKV.Checked = True Then
            txtFilename.Text = txtName.Text & " S" & txtSeason.Text & " E" & txtEpisode.Text & ".mkv"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm getting the error when the `If` statement is triggered in the CheckedChanged subs

```
Private Sub rdoAVI_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoAVI.CheckedChanged
        If rdoAVI.Checked = True Then
            txtFilename.Text = txtName.Text & " S" & txtSeason.Text & " E" & txtEpisode.Text & ".avi"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoMP4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoMP4.CheckedChanged
        If rdoMP4.Checked = True Then
            txtFilename.Text = txtName.Text & " S" & txtSeason.Text & " E" & txtEpisode.Text & ".mp4"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoMKV_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoMKV.CheckedChanged
        If rdoMKV.Checked = True Then
            txtFilename.Text = txtName.Text & " S" & txtSeason.Text & " E" & txtEpisode.Text & ".mkv"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: For the record, you should be applying the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself. You have basically the same code in all three `CheckedChanged` events with the file extension being the only difference. You should put the common code in a single method with a parameter for the extension, then call that method from each event handler. I would also recommend avoiding more than one concatenation operator at a time as it makes code hard to read and thus error-prone. I'd use string interpolation like this: `txtFilename.Text = $"{txtName.Text} S{txtSeason.Text} E{txtEpisode.Text}.{extension}"`.

Comment: You might also consider using a `NumericUpDown` control for the season and episode numbers, to avoid the possibility of someone entering a non-numeric value into a `TextBox`.

Comment: jmcilhinney! I haven't seen your name in a long time, not since I used to stalk vbforums. Thanks for your suggestions. I've rewritten the code for the radio buttons so one event handler handles them all, and will be implementing the NumericUpDown controls for Season and Episode

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid! When clearing the text boxes I hadn't used the ".Text" on txtLocation and txtFilename

Comment: Note that a WinForms `TextBox` has a `Clear` method. Setting the `Text` property to clear is not wrong per se, but calling `Clear` is more correct.